# Android Pay Auth and Capture

Tags: android, android-pay

Apple Pay supports a auth and capture by marking a transaction type as pending.
However in case of Android once we have the FullWallet. And in this we dont have a ability to set the transaction type.

So the question is does the auth and capture dependent completely on the payment service provider?

Or is there some types similar to Apple Pay of setting transaction type as Pending required on Android Pay as well?

I saw some service provider like Stripe which mentions that it supported Auth and Capture and in its FAQs for Apple Pay says that that also supports Auth and Capture. However, no such details about Android were listed. If anyone has tried before.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct on the first point - auth and capture depend solely on the payment service provider. This needs to be supported / handled by the payment processor (e.g. Stripe) in some form - you can think of Android Pay as just a thin layer that simplifies and secures the transfer of the user's card information to them (it's a bit more complex in reality, but that's the gig of it).